# Android: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE], but version is already higher than published

Tags: android, ionic-framework

guys!

I'm trying to update my android app, but I get this error message: 
[Upload Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdmYC.png)

When I try to run the app on my device, I get this error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE] 
>   You're trying to install apk with a lower versionCode that is already installed.
>   Either uninstall an app or increment the versionCode.

I have already increased the version code in AndroidManifest.xml (see code's first line below) and still get the same error.

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10101" android:versionName="1.1.1" package="com.ionicframework.fitme375349" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

This app is an ionic project.

Any help? Don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys!

Thanks for the help and support.

In some moment I set the version to 1.0.638 in Ionic config.xml. The androidManifest.xml generated had the versionCode 100638. When I increased the version in ionic config file to 1.0.639, the versionCode in AndroidManifest file was set to 10639 (don't know why). This is why I got the error in Google Play. After trying many different version numbers, I finally set the version in Ionic config file to 10.0.639 and the versionCode generated in AndroidManifest.xml was 100639. This version was accepted in google play.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to change in app level build.gradle file.

You have to increase the app version code every time you made an update.
make the version code to 10102

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10102" android:versionName="1.1.1" package="com.ionicframework.fitme375349" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: I have already increased the version and still get the same error. The version in Google Play is 100638

Comment: can you post the code of app level build.gradle file?

Comment: Any specific part? It's too long to post in here

Comment: defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

Comment: if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: This file is automatically generated by ionic